# Rails 5: implement 'add to favorites'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building an app where a `user(seller)` can create items and then another `user(viewer)` can view the items and `add to favorites` if he wants.

this what I've got thus far:

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title"
t.text "description"
t.string "image"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "category_id"
t.json "attachments"
end

create_table "favorites", force: :cascade do |t|
t.bigint "viewer_id"
t.string "favorited_type"
t.bigint "favorited_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["favorited_type", "favorited_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_favorited_type_and_favorited_id"
t.index ["viewer_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_viewer_id"
end
```

viewer.rb

```
class Viewer < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


has_many :favorites
has_many :favorite_items, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Item'
end
```

favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :viewer
 belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
end
```

favorite_items_controller.rb

```
class FavoriteItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_item

  def index
    @favorites = current_viewer.favorites
  end

  def create
    if Favorite.create(favorited: @item, viewer: current_viewer)
      redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item has been favorited'
    else
      redirect_to @item, alert: 'Something went wrong...*sad panda*'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Favorite.where(favorited_id: @item.id, viewer_id: current_viewer.id).first.destroy
    redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item is no longer in favorites'
  end

  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id] || params[:id])
  end
end
```

i added this to the views/items/show.html.erb in order to add or remove favorite.

```
<%- unless current_viewer.favorite_items.exists?(id: @item.id) -%>
    <%= link_to 'Add to favorites', favorite_items_path(item_id: @item), method: :post %>
<%- else -%>
    <%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_item_path(@item), method: :delete %>
<%- end -%>
```

and up to here everything works fine, when I click on the `add to favorites`... the link changes to `remove from favorites`... and when I click on `remove from favorites` the link changes back to `add to favorites`.

So now, I would like to implement the following but don't know how:
I want to loop thru the favorites and show all the favorite items on a `index.html.erb` along with each item details(title, price).

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is simple logic that you want to filter **FavouriteItems** from the **Items** so you need a table to store **FavouriteItems** in which you need **item_id**, **viewer_id**(user who selects the item to store in his favourite_items) that's it.

```
    class Viewer < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


#   has_many :favorites # I don't know why it is all here 
#   has_many :favorite_items, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Item'
  has_many :favorite_items
    end
```

Then you need to do this to your FavouriteItem class

```
class FavoriteItem < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :viewer
end
```

Hope it will give you the basic idea what you want.